# how to merge a column for the row that have a same value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

so i have a table such as

| Nama | No.ID | Tgl/Waktu | No.PIN | Kode Verifikasi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alif | 100061 | 17/12/2022 07:53:26 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 17/12/2022 13:00:25 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 19/12/2022 07:54:59 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 19/12/2022 16:18:14 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 20/12/2022 07:55:54 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 20/12/2022 16:16:16 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 21/12/2022 07:54:46 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 21/12/2022 16:15:41 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 22/12/2022 07:55:54 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 22/12/2022 16:15:59 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 23/12/2022 07:56:26 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 23/12/2022 16:16:56 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 17/12/2022 07:45:28 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 17/12/2022 13:00:23 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 19/12/2022 07:39:29 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 19/12/2022 16:17:37 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 20/12/2022 13:13:06 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 20/12/2022 16:16:14 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 21/12/2022 07:39:54 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 21/12/2022 16:15:38 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 22/12/2022 07:39:02 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 22/12/2022 16:15:55 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 23/12/2022 07:41:13 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 23/12/2022 16:16:25 |  | Sidik Jari |

with that table i want to make the row for name alif and budi to appear once so the output is like this
[image: i use picture because i cant use the formating in here]

how do i do it?

Comment: Why do you need merge? For saving file?

Comment: so the data output gonna be more presentable

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_index` and `swaplevel`.

Here is the example code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   "No.ID":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   "value":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})

df.set_index(['Name', 'No.ID'], append = True).swaplevel(0,2)
```